# How to make group of grids in extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I am getting column data and store from xml where I have three column.
I wanted to group column 1 on click of button. My button is placed on header of second column. again when i click on button it will get collapsed.

```
success: function(response) {
            var datas = response.responseXML;
            Ext.each(datas.getElementsByTagName("HEADER"), function(header) {
                this.buildField(header);
                this.buildColumn(header);
            }, this);

            Ext.each(datas.getElementsByTagName("G"), function(columnData) {
                //this.buildData(columnData);
               this.fieldLength = this.fields.length;
                this.record = [];

                for (i = 0; i < this.fieldLength; i++) {
                    var fieldName = this.fields[i].name
                    this.record[i] = columnData.getAttribute(fieldName);
                }


                this.data.push(this.record);
            }, this);

            var store2 = new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
                fields: this.fields,
            });
            store2.loadData(this.data);
    }
```

Code of grid is :

```
{
xtype: 'grid',
id: 'ABC_GRID',
autoHeight: 400,
store: store2,
sm: new Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel({singleSelect:true}),
frame: true,
columns: this.columns,
stripeRows: true,
  }
```

Thanks for your help